# How to click on the element through Selenium and Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I'm trying to click on the button but i cannot focus on it.

```
<td style="width:100%;height:63px" class="leftNavTabNormal nopad" onclick="selectPerspective('Production')">Production</td>
```

This is my code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@onclick='selectPerspective(Production)']")).click();
```

I cannot use the "class" because its not uniq

Please help me.

Comment: Please share exception details if you are getting.

Comment: Please share more HTML snippet for better understanding. because we cannot find a button in your HTML code. It just simple TD tag.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the element with text as **Production** you can use either of the following solutions:

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td.leftNavTabNormal.nopad[onclick*='Production']")).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='leftNavTabNormal nopad' and text()='Production']")).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your xpath missed apostrophe

Here is your page code

```
<td style="width:100%;height:63px" class="leftNavTabNormal nopad" onclick="selectPerspective('Production')">Production</td>
```

Here is your automation code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@onclick='selectPerspective(Production)']")).click();
```

Here is correct code with apostrophe

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@onclick='selectPerspective('Production')']")).click();
```